# How do you move buttons a bit down?

Tags: html, css

How do I move these buttons to the bottom, but not like bottom of the page, bottom, but just a bit, not too much. Here's a screenshot:

[image]

I want it to be a bit under the text while staying in that blue block. I'm new to HTML and CSS and I've been trying to move this damn thing for days but it's just not going.

```css
a {
  background-color: #00ccff;
  color: white;
  padding: 1em 1.5em;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

a:hover {
  background-color: #555;
}

a:active {
  background-color: black;
}

a:visited {
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" class="image">
  
  <div class="overlay">
    <div class="text"> Random text <br> <a href="#" style="Margin:auto">Button1</a>
      <a href="#" style="Margin:auto">Button2</a>
      </br>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's what [margin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin) is for. Don't use line breaks for layout.

Comment: Your screenshot doesn't match the code you've provided, so it's hard to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should to add "display" property to your "a" tag

```
a {display: inline-flex}
```

or:

```
a {display: inline-block}
```

you can see the example in this link
[enter link description here](https://codepen.io/kazemi/pen/YzNQLLJ)

Answer (score 0):

Try with any one of css properties mentioned below to `button`

1. Margin-top
2. Margin - bottom
3. padding-top
4. padding - bottom